# How to use Vuetify v-select in a focus lock

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using a Vuetify `v-select` in a filter which gets a focus lock when the filter is opened. Due to the `v-select` creating the `v-overlay-container` with the answer dropdown, it lies outside of the focus lock.

How can I work with both a `v-select` in a focus lock and enabling users to go through the answers using a keyboard?

Comment: You probably have to attach the menu to something inside your trap. VMenu has an [`attach`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-menu/#props-attach) prop, which you can set from v-select using its [`menu-props`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#props-menu-props) prop. Does that work?

Comment: Yup didnt see that I could pass menu-props. Attaching it to the select fixed it. Merci!